# What is the earliest time Tom Nook's daily announcement can be?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Every day Tom Nook gives a brief announcement, which also seems to directly correspond to daily progression ticks (anything that is scheduled to happen the next day, such as your tent getting upgraded to a house). However, the announcement doesn't occur at midnight (I know because I've restarted the game at midnight). What time does a "new day" officially start with Tom Nook's announcement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "new day" starts at **[5 a.m.](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21188657/day-reset-start-change-tomrrow)**, when anything that cycles daily resets.

Comment: Is that in-game time, local time, UTC time, or something else? (I'd probably know if I played the game)

Comment: @bobsburner It is 5am system time on the device

Comment: @bobsburner, to further answer your question, in-game time is the local real time on the system.  Game time is 1:1 with real world time.