# Does the new month start at midnight or 5am?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have yet to catch a Stringfish this month, and [Stringfish are set to go away at the end of the month in the northern hemisphere](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/365856/20306). However, the daily announcement [isn't for another 5 hours](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/365610/20306). Do I have until midnight on 4/1, or 5am on 4/1 to catch fish that are leaving this month?

Comment: .... until midnight _where_?  The switch has timezone support (and as an internet-enabled device needs to know about UTC anyways).  Does this mean you could set your clock "back in time" and still catch the fish?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The game is based on your system time, so it is simultaneously in-game time and system time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's midnight. I happened to be playing yesterday around midnight and I started catching April fish from midnight on.

Comment: Confirmed. I caught a Surgeonfish @ 12:15.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it switched over at midnight, as soon as it became April. I caught my stringfish with about fifteen minutes to spare. I checked its entry after midnight, and it showed it wasn't available during any hours and that it was currently considered April. It's hard to prove a negative, but I also didn't see any emperor butterflies after midnight. If you check their entry, I assume it looks similar to the stringfish one in terms of current hours of availability. Hope that helps.

[image: clutch stringfish]